# is this a 1 to 1 relationship

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to understand ER database design and trying to get my head around some relationships.

if I have a relationship like below is that consider 1 to 1, or 1 to many.

```
      bloodpackID----------------comes from------------DonorID
```

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bloodpack` to `Comes from` is `1 to 1`, and `Comes from` to `DonorID` is `many-to-1`, as can be seen by donor 1 contributing to both the 1 and 2 bloodpacks.

If `Comes from` did not exist this **would** be a `many-to-one` relationship, as a donor can give multiple bloodpacks, and a blood pack can only come from one donor.

If multiple donors can contribute to the same bloodpack, it would be a `many-to-many` relationship. In such a case, you would need to make use of a 'bridging' or **['associative entity'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)** table, as is seen in `Comes from` in your example above.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is great. comes from is not a table its the name of the relation as in "bloodpacks comes from donors". However, my textbook doesn't mention many to Many relations which is what had me confused.

Answer (score 1):

Bloodpack to comes from is 1 to 1

comes from to DonorID is many to 1